# Zend 2 Env specific application configs

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm following this guide to specifying specific config overloads based on our environment:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html

I'm creating a configuration tree like so in my config/autoload folder:

```
doctrine.global.php
doctrine.development.php
doctrine.staging.php
etc...
```

Then in my application.config.php file i'mve appended my "config_glob_paths" array like so:

```
sprintf(__DIR__ . '/autoload/' . '{,*.}{global,%s,local}.php', $env)
```

Where $env is "production / development / staging"

So you get the idea of what i'm trying to achieve.

For some reason, none of my added configurations are being picked up and merged into the config. If I remove all reference to global and local, then no configs are being pulled in.

Has anyone got this working, If you feel theres a better way to accomplish this i'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks for your help, and please ask if you need some clarification.

Comment: what it's in the $dir variable ?

Comment: Sorry updated that, it points to the autoload directory

Comment: I pasted this directly into one of my existing apps and it worked for me.  Any chance you're not setting the $env variable in the file?  When I omit that, I get a notice and the staging file I created isn't loaded (obviously).

Comment: What is the dump of your `ApplicationConfig` (`$serviceManager->get('ApplicationConfig')`)?